# Navigation Bar problems in SDK 4.2

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm new to SDK 4.2 and storyboards (like everyone I guess) but up til now they have played nice.

I have my initial view as a navigation controller ("is initial view controller") which has in it a View Controller. So far so good. After login here (authentication via web), this segues to a Tab Bar Controller containing three table views. Again, works fine.

Heres the problem. The first table view in the Tab bar controller  - I cannot the navigation bar for life, love or money. I can't change the back button, I cant change the title, I can't add right bar buttons, and this is either programmatically or using the storyboard.

At the end of the day all I want to do is:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addTapped:)];
```

But I can't work out how to do it. I've tried doing it from the UIView that segues to this view. Doesn't work. I've tried adding in storyboard. Doesn't work. I feel I should be somehow "doing it" to that initial navigation controller... but I have no reference to that and it doesn't have any associated code. And if I did... that would probably persist to other views.

Strangely, if I segue from the UITableView in question to another (eg from didSelectRowForIndexPath), the subsequently pushed table view seems happy to have its nav bar changed.

Stumped.

**EDIT:**
Sheesh. Ten minutes later I discover the answer. its the the TabBarController I needed. Like this:

```
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addTapped:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1- To change the navigation controller title:

```
[[self navigationController] setTitle:@"Your title"];
```

2- To add the right button:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addTapped:)];
[[self navigationItem]setRightBarButtonItem:stateButton];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think you'll find that was what I was already doing... anyway, I solved it. Thanks for your reply.